# Creating an asset library accessible from all classes

Tags: c++, unreal-4

The idea of what I'm trying to do is to create a class that will automatically pull in all of the assets needed using the ConstructorHelpers and store them in a library with IDs. Then from there, any class that includes the asset library should be able to access the library and the objects within.

So far I have created an empty C++ class and added all of the backend needed, and I've used the GameModeBase to instatiate the class as a static variable, however I can't include the asset library elsewhere and use it.

I have thought about creating an actor class and just plopping it into the world, but I really don't like the idea of that and would prefer something more robust.

I've tried searching for a way to do it online, but I can't seem to find it, does anyone know of a solution?

Below is the code I am using to create a singleton class and it will not compile, giving me an LNK2001 error

```
unresolved external symbol "private: static class AssetLibrary* AssetLibrary::Instance"
```

.h

```
static class UE4Testing_API AssetLibrary {
public:
    static AssetLibrary* GetInstance();

private:
    static AssetLibrary* Instance;

    AssetLibrary();
    ~AssetLibrary();
};
```

.cpp

```
AssetLibrary* AssetLibrary::GetInstance() {
    if(!Instance) {
        Instance = new AssetLibrary();
    }

    return AssetLibrary::Instance;
}

AssetLibrary::AssetLibrary() {

}

AssetLibrary::~AssetLibrary() {
    delete Instance;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/102665-question-about-global-singleton

Comment: I'm trying to make a singleton class but I keep getting an LNK2001 unresolved external. I'll update my post with the code